# how to select data on single click in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am presently working on tableau worksheets, the data is based on sales and order, it contains months, year, KPI, data value as some of its corresponding fields , what I am trying to do is when any month is selected it should return all the measure and sum of data value of that month as well as all the months before that particular month.

Comment: can you be more specific what you are trying to do?

Comment: have you tried this? http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/creating-filter-actions-dashboards

Comment: Another solution is to create a parameter, that can be used as a fancier filter (you can create a calculated field based on the parameter and do cool stuff)

Comment: Another thing is do a cool tooltip